# Javascript to create a PDF from PNG images and text?

Tags: javascript, pdf-generation

[Google Static Maps API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/staticmaps/) allows PNG images files of a map to be made programatically ([example PNG map](http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=512x512&maptype=roadmap%5C&markers=size:mid|color:red|San+Francisco,CA|Oakland,CA|San+Jose,CA&sensor=false)).

Using only javascript and a browser, is there a way to embed the PNG map image into a PDF file, along with some text, that the user can download?

From [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686280/convert-html-having-javascript-to-pdf-using-java-javascript) I found [this library pdf.js](http://maraksquires.com/pdf.js/) for converting text and lines into a PDF, but I cant figure out how I can also embed a PNG into the resulting PDF.

Comment: Javascript on a client machine is going to be Quite Limited in what it can do with PDF.  Now if you were to do it server-side, you've got a broad range of PDF software to choose from.  I suppose you could embed a Java applet and use one of the Java PDF libraries floating about *cough-iText-cough*.

Answer (score 0):

addImage(imageData, format, x, y, w, h)
but pdf.js currently has a empty implementation, so it's not working yet.