# how to convert a web page into pdf by button click in html5

Tags: javascript, html, pdf-generation

I have web page with containing data I want that when I click generate pdf button it should create pdf of that page.
And Save Locally .

I have searched alot but I am getting script to only create pdf by entering data is there any other way

Below is the method which I tried but it is not suitable I want to create whole page into pdf file.

jspdf.com

I also tried another code but it also does not create the file

```
  <script>


  function generatePDF(){} 

  var conv = new ActiveXObject("pdfServMachine.converter");
  conv.convert("http://www.google.com", "c:\\google.pdf", false);
  WScript.Echo("finished conversion");
 }

 </script>
 <body onload="generatePDF()">
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686280/convert-html-having-javascript-to-pdf-using-java-javascript

Comment: if this is a direct copy from your code than you need to write the word function correctly

Comment: @EyalAsheich yes i have made it write but nothing happens

Comment: Have you tried printing the page??

Comment: @AkhilrajNS the link you provides is fine can you help me overhere to add that code and where is the file saved

Comment: @stevnity no i have not tried do you know any method

Comment: can we provide html page link which we are trying make pdf or in local it is not working for me as given in link

Comment: As an alternative, you may try using Aspose.Pdf for .NET to convert HTML pages to PDF format. For related information, please visit http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/pdfnet/Convert+HTML+to+PDF+Format

Answer (score 3):

You didn't declare the function correctly. It should be `generatePDF(){`  instead of `generatePDF(){}` . Your `}` should be at the end of the function only.

Answer (score 1):

I am a bit late but let me tell you that, the code you are using is only compatible with old versions of Microsoft browser(i.e) because it contains WScript & ActiveX Component.

Yes, you can generate it with `jsPDF.js`. Just search this javascript file in google and download it locally then include it like shown below.

```
<script src="~/js/jspdf.js"></script>
<script>
  var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'letter');
  var specialElementHandlers = {
    '#editor': function (element, renderer) {
      return true;
    }          
  };     
  $('#btn_Pdfprint').click(function () {
    doc.fromHTML($('#myTabContent').html(), 25, 25, {
      'width': 790,
      'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
    });
    doc.save('mywebpagee.pdf');
    window.location.reload();
  });
</script>
```