# Use Javascript To Print Page As PDF (With Django)

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

I need to convert a web page to a PDF because it won't print/look correct if it isn't converted. This is because the web page is so big, that as an HTML document the browser will try and split it into multiple pages (not just vertically, which is fine, but horizontally, which is bad). Though I originally planned to do this on the server side with Django, I realized that virtually all of the available libraries were written for python2, when I was using python 3.

So my only other option is client side. The only thing I could find on stackoverflow was this: [convert HTML ( having Javascript ) to PDF using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686280/convert-html-having-javascript-to-pdf-using-java-javascript), but all of the answers were in Java, not javascript.

Comment: Is this your webpage? Just specify a print stylesheet that allows nothing to overflow the page horizontally. `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/stylesheets/print.css" media="print">`

Comment: @minitech There's no easy way just to "scale" everything on the page down. The ratio of the width and height are exactly those that would be printed, but the size is five or six times as big.

Comment: Are all your dimensions specified in ems like they should be? ;)

Comment: @minitech I didn't write the webpage, but I have "control" over it. It was written without ems and with a table layout.

Comment: Hmm… what kind of control? You can put scripts in it?

Comment: @minitech I can do everything except reformat it visually. It has to look the same.

Answer (score 2):

I think the most ideal solution would be to change the style so that it was more printer friendly rather than making it into a pdf.

If it really does have to be a pdf created with Javascript, there's a library jsPDF http://parall.ax/products/jspdf out there for creating pdfs with Javascript.  You would have to write something on your own to parse the page to create a matching pdf.

If you can use php, I recommend using dompdf, which was written specifically to translate webpages into pdfs, so there would be much less work involved there.  https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf  I've actually used this library, and it seems decent, though it doesn't support all css styling.