# How to Convert Html Page to PDF using javascript

Tags: javascript, pdf

I have a java Application which view few results in a  web page , I want to save those results into PDF file which user click on a button "Export to PDF" Button. Can any one please help me to use which  technology. I am  really aware of this.

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/152470/how-to-convert-an-html-page-to-pdf-using-javascript

Comment: possible duplicate of [convert HTML ( having Javascript ) to PDF using java / javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686280/convert-html-having-javascript-to-pdf-using-java-javascript)

Comment: This is not the duplicate question.. Probably it might be posted my different user..

Answer (score 3):

The simple and best way is to make use of existing libraries. You can get it done either in server side or in client side. If you choose the server side, go for [iText PDF Api](http://itextpdf.com) Otherwise you can use [jspdf](http://parall.ax/products/jspdf). Both will provide their own methods, you could use it.

Comment: I am looking into JspDF file . this shows how to save the file file into  PDF with  static text in it.. Can u please help me in showing sample codes to store the  web page into pdf when user click on button

Comment: make use of .fromHTML() method which helps writing HTML contents into pdf file. I couldnt find the exact docs for it. But can you can find some examples by googling it !!!

Comment: I spent a day on JSPDF. It doesn't support CSS file references. It also doesn't support multipages. I added Html2Convas, it solved the CSS issue. But found no solution for multipages. gave up on it!